# Purescript Effects: Prevent deep nesting

Tags: purescript

Right now, `main` has the following signature:

```
main :: Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe (Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)))
```

I'd like to have the following:

```
main :: Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)
```

---

```
findItem :: forall e. IsElement e => e -> Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)
findItem e = getElementsByClassName "thing" (toElement e) >>= (item 0)

-- main :: Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)
main = (map findItem) <$> (window >>= document >>= body)
```

**What is the best way to do this?**

Of course, I could do the following:

```
findItem :: forall e. IsElement e => Maybe e -> Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)
findItem (Just e) = getElementsByClassName "findItemEdit" (toElement e) >>= (item 0)
findItem Nothing = pure Nothing

main :: Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)
main = findItem =<< body =<< document =<< window
```

But I'd like to not have the `Maybe` handling in the `findItem` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `traverse :: forall a b eff.  (a -> Eff eff b) -> Maybe a -> Eff eff (Maybe b)`. The function is more general, but that's how you'll want to use it. Whenever you find yourself wanting to "swap" two types, like `Maybe a -> Eff eff (Maybe a)`, or `Maybe (List a) -> List (Maybe a)`, you can use `traverse` or `sequence`.

Specifically, your `main` would look like:

```
main :: Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)
main = do
  mdocBody <- window >>= document >>= body
  mmitem <- traverse findItem mdocBody
  -- mmitem has type `Maybe (Maybe Element)`
  -- we can use `join` to collapse
  pure (join mmitem)
```

Or, as point free,

```
main :: Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)
main =
  window >>= document >>= body 
    >>= map join <<< traverse findItem
```

Comment: This won't work. Traverse takes `a -> Eff eff b`, but the OP's function is `a -> Eff eff (Maybe b)`.

Comment: Even though I generally prefer point free, it's much easier to reason with your first example. Thank you so much for updating your answer!

Comment: For those following, I find the point free version to be more clear written as: `main = window >>= document >>= body >>= traverse findItem >>> map join`

Comment: Yeah, PureScript's `<<<` operator makes it less clear that it's a single part of the bind pipeline -- Haskell's `f >>= g >>= h . k` groups `h . k` visually a little nicer, to me. Keeping a consistent right-to-left or left-to-right direction is good too :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [MaybeT](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-transformers/3.5.0/docs/Control.Monad.Maybe.Trans) monad transformer:

```
main = runMaybeT do
  b <- MaybeT (window >>= document >>= body)
  MaybeT (findItem b)
```

`MaybeT` is a newtype for a `Maybe` wrapped inside a monad `m` (in our case `m` is `Eff (dom :: DOM)`):

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT (m (Maybe a))
```

and its `bind` handles nesting and unnesting in just the way you'd like it to:

```
bind (MaybeT x) f = MaybeT do
  x >>= case _ of
    Nothing -> pure Nothing
    Just y -> case f y of MaybeT m -> m
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is to use the `Maybe` catamorphism, which would essentially take the `findItem` from your first example and turn it into the `findItem` from your second example:

```
main :: Eff (dom :: DOM) (Maybe Element)
main = maybe (pure Nothing) findItem =<< body =<< document =<< window
```

Comment: Yeah, your second edit works! I don't love the elegance of the solution to this problem. Is this a common approach for reducing nesting when morphisms have side-effects?